# I was not able to get the output for this below coding in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table with 3 columns like eid, ename, salary. So I wanted to display all employees name with their salaries by using cursor and records. If there is any mistakes in my code please let me know.

```
 DECLARE CURSOR emp_c IS select ename,salary from emp2;

 TYPE rec_2 IS RECORD 
 {
    v_name  varchar2(50);
    v_sal   number(10);
 };

 r1    rec_2;

 BEGIN
    open emp_c;
    loop
      fetch emp_c into r1;
      exit when emp_c%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line('name='||r1.v_name||'salary='||r1.v_sal);
    end loop;
 END;
```

Comment: Syntax for declaring a record type is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99971). Cursor loops are defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way is:

```
declare

cursor c_emp is
select
  emp.ename,
  emp.salary
from
  emp2 emp;

begin

for l_emp_rec in c_emp
loop
dbms_output.put_line('name='||l_emp_rec.ename||'salary='||l_emp_rec.salary);
end loop;

end;
```